# Check all divs have the same class or not

Tags: jquery

For example I have to do it manually like this:

```
function checkDivUppersClosed() {
    var allOpened = true;
    $('.classUpper').each(function (index, domEle) {
        allOpened &= $(this).parent().hasClass('closed');
    });
    return allOpened;        
}
```

I know that if I select `$('.closed').size()` will return the length as well. But in my case, some divs have the class classUpper but not at all.

Comment: Does `.closed` represent being hidden? If so you can make this *much* shorter, for example `$('.classUpper:visible').length === 0` would mean they're all closed.

Comment: So you just want all the divs that have a common class? Or, as the title states, you want to know if all the divs have the same class, and return what?  It seems from your code snippet that you are looking for the former.

Comment: Agree with James - can you make this question a bit clearer? Exactly what are you trying to achieve? Sample markup might help, too.

Comment: Nick: no, I was searching if some divs contain a specific class. your solution below is correct ;)

James and Bobby: from a class of a child div of ALL same parent divs, I need to check if the parent divs of these children divs have the class 'closed' or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do the literal version of your current check you can do this:

```
return $('.classUpper').parent(':not(.closed)').length;
```

This would return the count that aren't closed (parents of these elements that do [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) have the `closed` class).  You could use the number as a true/false check still, or add a `=== 0` to be explicit.

Though if the `closed` class is being added to hide them, you can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector, like this:

```
return $('.classUpper:visible').length === 0;
```

Comment: are `.size()` and `.length` the same thing?  I thought jQuery only had `.size()` and arrays had `.length`?

Comment: @Bob - A jQuery object *is* an array of DOM elements, if you [look in the source](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L180), a call to `.size()` is just a wrapper to `.length` :)

Comment: i know it has an array of dom elements inside of it, but I thought the length was private, i didn't know the property was maintained by jQuery's code

Comment: @Bob: the [merge function](http://github.com/jquery/jquery) keeps .length up-to-date (merge is used by the main selector engine).

Comment: @Bob - A jQuery object inherits the `length` property when it inherits some methods from `Array` like `.push()`. As such, the `length` property behaves similar (but not identical) to that in `Array`. When for example `.push()` is used, the `length` property updates automatically. But in some cases as @Bobby Jack noted with `.merge()` an `Array` method is not used, so jQuery needs to update it manually. Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/SuHwx/

Comment: ...correction, jQuery initializes `length` as it wouldn't be initialized until/unless an Array method is called.

Comment: $('.classUpper').parent(':not(.closed)').length;
=> is really the solution that I was looking for.

Great!@

Thanks a lot Nick & also to all ;)

Answer (score -1):

Why not:

```
$('.classUpper .closed')
```

Comment: This checks the two classes on the *same* element, he's checking for one class on the child, another on the parent.

Comment: @Bobby - Now it checks for a *child* class of close, rather than a parent :)

Comment: OK, I fully admit: I have NO idea what the questioner is trying to do! ;)

Comment: -1 This checks for elements with class .classUpper and gets all the children with .closed.  I think you meant to write: `.classUpper.closed`

Comment: @Bob - That's what he had originally, neither is quite there though, the OP is checking if the *parent* of a `.classUpper` is `.closed` :)

Comment: @Nick so couldn't he do `$(.closed.classUpper).size() == $(.classUpper).size()`

Comment: @Bob: "('.closed.classUpper').size()" will always, presumably, return 0 since the structure is not quite as it might have seemed. There are .classUpper elements INSIDE .closed ones.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to perform an operation on some elements that match your criteria then you can use:

```
$('.classUpper.closed')
```

Comment: That's not the structure that the questioner is working with, as Nick has pointed out (it's a very confusingly worded question!). I think the structure is something like: <div class="closed"><div class="classUpper"></div></div>